# Quoting \ with grave accent not working for comments

Tags: support, comments, markdown

I've recently faced difficulty in [commenting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258860/how-do-i-grep-the-lines-based-on-dot#comment447905_258860). Actually I want to show `\` and `\\` but unable to....

So, How do quote grave accent with **`**?

Example: I've used following text in comment to this question:

> This is not working: `\` and `\\`

[@Andrew T.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/241919/andrew-t) suggested [this](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4519476#4519476) but it is not working as expected mark-down (see 2<sup>nd</sup> comment)

Comment: This is not working: `\` and `\\`

Comment: This is not a solution: `\\`

Comment: Well, this is possible: This is not about Bash's behaviour of ``\`` or ``\\``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape the backtick itself by having two backticks:

```
This is not about Bash's behaviour of ``\`` or ``\\``
```

Comment: Checking if ``\`` and ``\\`` works or not.... [solved]